# Draw visual bounds around UV islands

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

Is there any way to draw visual bounds around UV islands to represent edge padding?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "visual bounds"? Do you want to draw in some way line along the bounds of each island?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. A line that is offset by a set number of pixels.

Comment: By a set number of pixels? I don't think it's possible to do with that precision. You can use Face selection masking when painting to select one face of the UV island, use Ctrl+L to select all the faces from that island (there should be seams for this to work) and enter Texture paint without deselecting; then with Face selection masking you will paint only on one island. That doesn't provide with precision of how many pixels do you want to paint

Comment: I’ve added a picture to illustrate what I have in mind. This is to ease up manual UV packing when trying to keep certain distance between islands.